# How do I edit a position or open source project in a Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I'm trying to edit my Developer Story, I see "edit" links for most sections. But I don't see any "edit" links next to my positions or open source projects. How do I edit these? I'm no longer at a position, for example, and I cannot edit the position to reflect that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit links for positions are 'hidden' behind the menu, which is shown when you click on the settings wheel:

[image]

This is different from the header sections, which have an edit button when you hover over them:

[image]

Comment: Wow, not obvious at all. Hope that gets revised.

Comment: It is especially poor design since the only two options available in that drop-down menu are "Edit" and "Delete", the latter being a special case of the former. A single "Edit" link would not only be more discoverable and consistent, but wouldn't lose any significant functionality. The Jobs team seems to be having the same problem as the Docs team: they are too focused on making things look cool, as opposed to making them functional. Remember when Stack Overflow took the programming world by storm? It was fairly ugly, but *highly* functional.