# How do I edit the title and links in my "developer story"?

Tags: support, developer-story

Where I can go to edit the titles and relevant links in my "developer story". I've updated my profile, but none of that information appears to be reflected in the developer story. The individual items I can find the menu for editing per [How do I edit a position or open source project in a Developer Story?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339495/how-do-i-edit-a-position-or-open-source-project-in-a-developer-story), but I'm at a loss for updating the profile title, blog links, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be on a browser that supports "hover" - so viewing and editing from mobile/touch focused browsers won't show you the option. When working with a laptop or desktop based browser, hovering over the various areas will expose the "Edit" button for updating.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here:

[Please replace the Edit button on Personal Statement (in Developer Story) with an Edit link/gear icon so that mobile users can edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363655/please-replace-the-edit-button-on-personal-statement-in-developer-story-with-a)

... this whole problem of being unable to edit in **a mobile browser** (ex. Safari on an iPad) could be resolved by getting rid of the **Edit button** and using instead the gear icon with **Edit menu link**, as is already used in the **other sections of Developer Story**, like here (screen shot taken on my iPad):
[image]

Editing the others section using the Edit link from the gear icon works on mobile (tested on iPad using the browser). So, perhaps all that is needed is for that gear icon with Edit **link** to be placed on all sections that are editable and to do away with the flaky Edit **button**.