# Please replace the Edit button on Personal Statement (in Developer Story) with an Edit link/gear icon so that mobile users can edit

Tags: feature-request, developer-story, user-interface, mobile-web, ipad

On an iPad (and perhaps other mobile devices?), even with JavaScript enabled, the blue Edit button does not appear in the Personal Statement area, thus making it impossible to edit the Personal Statement. See the screenshot below and see the red text inside.

[image]

All other areas of Developer Story, use the **gear icon** which, when clicked, shows a menu with an **Edit link**, and thus allows editing.

Please make the Personal Statement area in Developer story use the same gear icon with Edit menu as all other sections.

Why the inconsistency? Making this small change will solve many problems for mobile users and improve the user experience while not negatively affecting other users.

Comment: Hold down on it for a moment.

Comment: Thanks. I am not clear exactly what you are suggesting I hold down on. What is "it" specifically?

Comment: Anywhere in your example yellow box seems to work on my iPad - an edit button appears. Not exactly intuitive maybe.

Comment: Please show me the HTML source code for that page for the Edit button. I'll wait for some other iPad users to also confirm.

Comment: Please also include the few lines immediately above and below the Edit button HTML.